# how to sort with the third column

Tags: bash

I know there have been some questions about it. I tried the methods they mentioned but it does not work.

My data is in Book1.csv file like this:[image]

Then I used bash code: `sort -r -n -k 3,3 Book1.csv > sorted.csv`

But the outcome is not what I want:[image]
I want the outcome to be like:[image]

In addition, since the first colume is Id, the third column is score, I want to print the ids with the highest scores. In this case, it should print the two id whose score are 50, like this:`TRAAAAY128F42A73F0 TRAAAAV128F421A322` How to achieve it?

Comment: Does adding `-t ,` to your `sort` command sort it like you want?

Comment: Thank you Daniel!. adding  adding -t , to my sort command works well! Do you have any idea how to get the ids with the highest scores?

Comment: To get the first `x` rows, you could pipe sort output to head -n x. When the row are sorted by score, that gives you the `x` highest scores.

Comment: What if i don't know x? I want to return all the ids with the highest score

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your csv is comma separated and not another delimiter this is one way to do it. However, I think there is probably away to do most of this if not all in awk, unfortunately my knowledge is limited with awk so here is how I would do it quickly.

First according to the comments the `-t` flag of `sort` resolved your sorting issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
#set csv file to variable
mycsv="/path/csv.csv"

#get the third value of the first line after sorting on the third value descending.
max_val=$(sort -t, -k3,3nr $mycsv | head -n1 | cut -f3)
#use awk to evaluate the thrid column is equal to the maxvalue then print the first column. 
#Note I am setting the delimiter to a comma here with the -F flag
awk -F"," -v awkmax="$maxval" '$3 == awkmax {print $1}' $mycsv
```

Comment: you're enamored with the `<<<` feature ;-) . why not `maxVal=$(sort ... $mcsv | head -n1|cut -f3`? (Needs a little more work, but less code means fewer places for it to break in the future;-) > Good luck to all.

Comment: haha yes I am :) but very true to all points. Thanks for the info, just learned something new!

Comment: You want a `,` after the `-t` flag. The `-t` flag gives the field separator.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMartin

Answer (score 0):

While the printing all IDs with the highest score can be done in bash with basic unix commands, I think it's better to, at this point, switch to an actual scripting language. (unless you're in some very limited environment)

Fortunately, `perl` is everywhere, and this task of printing the ids with the largest scores can be done as one (long) line in `perl`:

```
perl -lne 'if (/^([^,]*),[^,]*,\s*([^,]*)/) {push @{$a{$2}},$1; if($2>$m) {$m=$2;}} END {print "@{$a{$m}}";}' Book1.csv
```